# Get focus on tkinter program after pc is unlocked

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter program written in python 3.3.3. I see myself in the need of making the the program get focus when the user unlocks the computer. I don't really know how to go ahead and start with this, users have a .exe version of the program that I created with cxfreeze. I f i need to modify the .py and create another .exe, that wouldn't be a problem.

After some research I found that one can use the ctypes module to lock the computer, but it's not very helpful because i need to know if it is locked or unlocked. I also saw commands from win32com, but i can't seem to be able to find a way to trigger a command when it gets unlocked.

What is the best way to get focus on my program after the computer is unlocked??

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try an autoit3 script/forum. That's nothing to do with neither python or tkinter: you need to find event rised by win manager and move focus to app. If you keep window „on top”, it may get focus by default

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer this specifically for 'unlock' event (if there even is one in the GUI; I can't find one by cursory search.).

But I think the real answer is to change the question.  Having a program simply take focus when user unlocks the display is very un-Windows-ish behavior.  The Windows user expects to see the desktop just as s/he left it before the display was locked -- why does s/he want to see your program on top when unlocking, regardless of why Windows might have locked the display?

Maybe you want to recast your program as something that runs in the background and pops up a notification (in the notification area on the right side of toolbar) when it wants user to do something?

Comment: The reason why the program has to be on top when it is unlocked is because the tool is a time tracker and they forget to change they are doing, by having that feature we will have less "forgetting" issues. I have tried this: http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/see_if_my_workstation_is_locked.html but i don't seem to understand how it works